# Drupal Blocks/Widgets Width / Height Parameters

Tags: php, debugging, drupal, widget, block

The site I am maintaining has bugs in the header and widget blocks. How do I change this?

1. Search bar is out of alignment with nav menu.
2. News and Events widgets overextends if too much text is displayed.
   a. The news widget is from an automatic feed.

http://cafes.calpoly.edu

One error only shows in Chrome browser. In Safari I at least don't see the News widget over extending but the search bar in the main header navigation menu appears to have a distorted div in all browsers.

I am new to Drupal but am pretty familiar with Wordpress.

Is there a module I can download to enable me to fix this? If so, what code snippet could I use to establish the proper parameters for these blocks?

Comment: These are all simple CSS issues as far as I can see. Nothing really drupal related

Comment: Can I install a CSS module? Because I currently do not have backend access.

Comment: While you should really change the css file, but there is a css module: https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector

Answer (score 0):

1) Option one reduce li font size if client is ok with it
font-size: 0.75em;

This worked for me and you the search bar was fixed.

2) Second option is to trim the text length. There is only so much u can fit in those tight cells.

abt the news widget I don't see anything wrong.

Answer (score -1):

There is no "CSS" module in Drupal. To fix the issues you've mentioned you need to make small changes in the css files. To fix the search box aligment you should reduce the font-size of the menu items.
You will need at least ftp access to the site.